# Rspec shared example: Access parameter in a helper method

Tags: rspec

Suppose I create an Rspec shared example group with one parameter (the business purpose of the tests are irrelevant, it is an overly simplified version of my current codebase):

```rb
shared_examples "some example group" do |parameter|
  it "does something" do
    puts "parameter=#{parameter}"

    print_the_parameter
  end

  def print_the_parameter
    puts "parameter=#{parameter}"
  end
end
```

I am able to access the `parameter` as a variable just fine with the `it` test block. However, I am running into an "undefined local variable or method" when I try to access `parameter` from a method. Why is that? I have proven in my codebase (and is prevalently shown in Rspec documentation) that the parameter is available in test blocks, lifecycle methods like `before`, and in `let` variable declarations. But why not helper methods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Ruby scoping, the parameter passed to the block is available within the block's closure. So the evaluated string `"parameter=#{parameter}"` being within the closure works just fine.

What you're trying to do the same as is this:

```
b = "Hi!"

def a
  puts b
end

a()
# NameError (undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object)
```

The solution is to wrap parameter in a `let`, (note I strongly encourage using a different name to prevent confusion about precedence.) e.g.

```
let(:param) { parameter }
```

This is the same (roughly) as doing:

```
b = "Hi!"

def a
  puts b
end

define_method(:b) { b }

a()
# Hi!
# => nil
```